# mock php's resource type for unittesting

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have to write tests for a php Class that uses a resource type created by an apache extension we use, but let's say it's a database class with the mysql resource type.

obviously i'd like to mock those global functions, but how to fake the return type when the class checks if the resource was created fine?

the Resource page in php's doc even have one comment complaining about the inability of mocks for testing. Is that the final answer?

let's say i have the (lame example) code:

```
class DB {
  function init(){
    $this->handle = mysql_connect('myserver');
    if( get_resource_type($this->handle) != 'mysql' ) return false;
      return true;
    }
}
```

and then the tests that test for a success and a failure, by mocking `mysql_connect`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're a bit far off. Actually, resources are perfectly fine to test with PHP, you can get their type etc. pp..

What's not easy to test are the dependencies they represent. You normally don't inject those but you code around those resources. Let's call it object invert oriented.

Central is the object (resource) and the code belonging to it in procedural style always has the dependency of that resource. Let's take curl as an example:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($handle);
```

As this procedural style around the `$handle` object it's not mockable in the sense to replace the functionality with a mock if curl is a dependency of some other code. So you need to wrap it first to make it injectable:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$curl = new Curl($url);
$curl->exec();
```

This comes with the price that you need to convert the resource centric object orientation in a plain old PHP object:

```
class Curl
{
    private $handle;
    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->handle = curl_init($url);
    }
    public function exec() {
        return curl_exec($this->handle);
    }
}
```

It's easy now to mock it. The good thing is, this often is possible, so normally resources itself shouldn't put any restrictions for testing, it's merely some encapsulation that's missing so you need to add it first.

Some APIs, like the imap extension, don't allow to create a clean object interface due to global static state, in case of the IMAP extension it's the error handling. But still it's getting close and if the deficiencies are documented, that helps, too.

Comment: i don't see you point... what if I was to test this class, and right before curl_exec it checked the type of resource was the original curl type? and i didn't want it using real curl functions?

Comment: @gcb: You either want to unit-test the `Curl` class (when you do this, the handle is an internal and does not need to be tested) or you want to test some other component that makes use of the `Curl` class, then you can give it a mock of the `Curl` class.

Comment: if i am testing the `Curl` class, how then i avoid if from hitting webservers and being inconsistent?

Comment: @gcb: What do you mean? You either want to test the integration of it against webservers, or you don't want to. So you assume that it works, so you can mock it. Or you expect it to fail, so you mock it as well.

Comment: exactly. let's say, if curl return a resource it pass the success test. if curl return a non-resource it pass the failure test. how do i pass a resource and NOT depend on external workings in curl? (this is overkill for curl, but is a perfect analogy for the case i have)

Comment: For example, you could make `Curl` throw an exception: `if (! $this->handle = curl_init($url)) throw new Exception('Failed to initialize.');`. You then don't need to rely on the inner state (the handle). The `Curl` type will signal if it can't do what it wants to do / needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

This may help people who are trying to mock out PHP functions like Curl:  https://github.com/IcecaveStudios/isolator

It allows you to isolate them from your code, enabling you to use normal mocking techniques.

Comment: This library is a much better solution than the isolator I mentioned above:  https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock